# RestSharp: Deserialize Xml to c# Object return null

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, restsharp

i've an xml from some api :

```
<auditypes>
     <auditype code="a" description="aaa"/>
     <auditype code="b" description="bbb"/>
     <auditype code="c" description="ccc"/>
     <auditype code="d" description="ddd"/>
     <auditype code="e" description="eee"/>
</auditypes>
```

and mapping as object in C# class :

```
    public class auditypes
    {
        public List<auditype> auditype { get; set; }
    }

    public class auditype
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```

I call it with this function :

```
    public List<auditypes> Execute<auditypes>(RestRequest request) where auditypes : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = "https://www.myurl.com/auditypes";
        var response = client.Execute<auditypes>(request);

        return response.Data as List<auditypes>;
    }

    public List<auditypes> GetCall()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
        request.RootElement = "auditype";
        return Execute<auditypes>(request);
    }
```

but it always return null, does anyone knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it work for me :)

```
public auditypes Execute<auditypes>(RestRequest request) where auditypes : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = "https://www.myurl.com/auditypes";
    var response = client.Execute<auditypes>(request).Data;

    return response;
}

public auditypes GetCall()
{
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
    return Execute<auditypes>(request);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The generic parameter passed to `Execute<T>` is the type that should be deserialized by the `RestSharp`  library. That means that your `response.Data` property is already of type `T`, which in your case is `auditypes`. But when you `return` you try to cast it to a `List<auditypes>` where no such cast exists.

Also, there is no need for the type constraint, as your method is not generic as it accepts an explicit type.

Refactor your method:

```
public auditypes Execute<auditypes>(RestRequest request)
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = "https://www.myurl.com/auditypes";
    var response = client.Execute<auditypes>(request);

    return response.Data;
}
```

Comment: it still not return the xml data, but it return `length=0` not retun `null`

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving a `List<auditypes>` abd not just `auditypes`?

Comment: yes i received that, the return type is `List<auditypes>` but `Data` count = 0

Comment: Is the XML you posted a full one? Or are there more `auditypes` attributes?

Comment: ya, is the full one. anything wrong with my deserialization maybe?

Comment: Refactored my answer. Try it now

Comment: I got an error when try it(but forgot what is exactly). The problem isnt in my auditypes function btw, i found it in my answer. Thanks :)